# Why are Python classes with identical attributes considered "incompatible" by type checkers?

Tags: python

If two classes have the same set of attributes, why do Python type checkers warn that they aren't compatible?

In the example below I could, in reality, pass a `T` to `wants_s` and all would be fine. So why don't type checkers "allow" this?

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class S:
    foo: str
    bar: str


@dataclass
class T:
    foo: str
    bar: str


def wants_s(s: S):
    print(s.foo)
    print(s.bar)


t = T(foo="foo", bar="bar")
wants_s(t)  # type checkers complain here
```

---

#### Pyright

```
  error: Argument of type "T" cannot be assigned to parameter "s" of type "S" in function "wants_s"
    "T" is incompatible with "S" (reportGeneralTypeIssues)
```

#### Mypy

```
error: Argument 1 to "wants_s" has incompatible type "T"; expected "S"
```

#### Pytype

```
Function wants_s was called with the wrong arguments [wrong-arg-types]
         Expected: (s: S)
  Actually passed: (s: T)
```

Comment: Just because they have attributes with the same name doesn't mean they're equivalent. It could just be a coincidence.

Comment: As to why type checkers complain, I'm not sure. Is it necessary to have an explicit check for the type though? Why can't you use duck typing + EAFP?

Comment: @Barmar So you're saying that classes should explicitly say that they are equivent to one another, rather than relying on having signatures with the same data types? That makes sense I suppose. There must be some good examples of where assuming equivalence would have some insane outcomes...

Comment: A simplified case is when you have two empty classes - the instances are obviously of different types even though both are empty. If it were otherwise it would be weird. Imagine having two classes: Person and Cat. Both could have a single attribute "name" but an instance of class Person is definitely not an instance of type Cat.

Comment: Basically, the class names are different, so it is not the same type. Type checks what class it belongs to, not the attributes.

Comment: By default, the type system is a *nominal type system*. You are assuming a *structural type system*. Python provides `typing.Protocol` to allow for structural subtyping. An example of a language that has structural subtyping by default is `TypeScript`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [MyPy's guide to Duck Type compatibility](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/duck_type_compatibility.html). They provide limited support for duck type handling natively, but as stated in the docs:

> This is [only] supported for a small set of built-in types:
>
> - int is duck type compatible with float and complex.
> - float is duck type compatible with complex.
> - bytearray and memoryview are duck type compatible with bytes.
> - In Python 2, str is duck type compatible with unicode.
>
> [...]
>
> You can also often use [Protocols and structural subtyping](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html#protocol-types) to achieve a similar effect in a more principled and extensible fashion. Protocols don’t apply to cases like int being compatible with float, since float is not a protocol class but a regular, concrete class, and many standard library functions expect concrete instances of float (or int).

This comes down to a fundamental conflict between the features provided to the user by dynamic typing and duck typing and the amount of work needed to be done by a linter or type hinter.

Guido's [initial proposal for built-in type hinting](https://quip.com/r69HA9GhGa7J), which has evolved into [PEP 483](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0483/) goes into much more detail on the topic and the methods for defining hinted subtype relationships.

Comment: Yes, this stuff about structural subtyping and protocol classes is what I was looking for here.

Comment: If anyone wants to know why I asked this question in the first place, [this other question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71299591/2071807) gets closer to explaining that!

Answer (score 3):

The issue you are talking about is called "Duck Typing". You can find more information about it by Googling the term.

Python explicitly allows duck typing.  If an object has a `swim` method, then you can call `swim()` and hope that it does the right thing.

One of the jobs of a linter is to protect you against duck typing.  If you're saying that a method accepts a `Duck`, then the type checker's job is make sure that you only pass it an instance of a `Duck`.  Sure, you can pass it an instance of a `Whale`, and that whale also has a `swim` method.  But what happens when you later decide you want your duck to `fly()`?

The solution to your problem is Protocols.  You might have a protocol `Swimmable` indicating that the object has a `swim()` method.  Then your method makes it argument type be `Swimmable`.

In short, the linter is doing its job.